# What's the criteria to earn the health trophy?

Tags: monaco

Each level has four trophies you can earn. There's only one trophy that I haven't determined the exact criteria for:

- 1P: Complete the mission single player, or by yourself
- MP: Complete the mission multiplayer, or with one or more teammates
- +: Not 100% sure, have a few ideas
- ♦: Complete the mission collecting all coins (cleaned out)

What is the exact criteria for the health trophy? Here are a few of my guesses:

- Complete the mission without using a health pack
- Complete the mission without you personally dying
- Complete the mission without anyone dying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last guess is correct - complete the mission **without any player dying**. In singleplayer mode, this only applies to you. In multiplayer, however, it applies to all players.

There's no problem with enemy characters dying or using health packs, though.