# How does one obtain the Z Trophy?

Tags: monaco

I know how to get all trophies except the trophy labelled 'Z'. I have no idea how to get it and I haven't found even a mention of it anywhere online.

Comment: It's just named "Z"? you're right about it not being anywhere online (even the official achievement list)... so to me it sounds bugged?

Comment: @JLaBella Trophies are not achievements, they are in-game awards and 'badges of honor' for beating levels under certain restrictions  (not dying, for example).  However, as far as I'm away there is no trophy labelled Z.  [There should only be four, as outlined here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126679/whats-the-criteria-to-earn-the-health-trophy)

Comment: I believe the Z trophy is for completing the level in Zombie mode. I'll check.

Comment: I've gotten all four trophies on all levels, and have never even heard of a 'Z' trophy. This question definitely has piqued my interest.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, just confirmed that the Z trophy is earned by beating the level in Zombie mode ("Zonaco").

Just to note, there are some gameplay differences between Zombie mode and Classic mode. For instance, in Zombie mode, the enemies are a bit tougher but you get more ammo.